# AngularJS directive not inserting values into template when using an isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Given the following directive:

```
angular.module('news.directives', [])
    .directive('newsArticle', function($location, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict:    'AE',
            replace:     'true',
            templateUrl: 'partials/pages/news/directives/article.html',
            scope:       true
        };
    });
```

And the following template:

```
<div id="story-{{item.id}}" ng-class="{'red': item.active, 'story-container': true}">
    <div class="story-banner-image"></div>
    <div class="story stationary">{{ item.title | words: 10 }}</div>
    <div class="story-banner-content"></div>
</div>
```

And the following call to the directive:

```
<news-article ng-repeat="item in news">
</news-article>
```

This works. But if I want to use an isolated scope and expose a single item:

```
scope: {
    item: '@'
}

// or

scope: {
    news: '@'
}

// or

scope: {}
```

Then it doesn't. All of the `{{item.property}}` tags specified in the template return a null value (empty string). Why doesn't `item` exist in the isolated scope?

Comment: Of course, because this is isolated scope, why are you surprised.

Comment: Because I would assume that the isolated scope would contain either item or news because its bound to the actual element in ng-repeat. It's quite clearly inheriting it's parent properties when scope is set to true, but it's not inheriting when I tell it what it should inherit.

Comment: This should also work great if you don't use isolated scope, in case you want to go that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's quite clearly inheriting it's parent properties when scope is set to true, but it's not inheriting when I tell it what it should inherit.

You problem is that you are confused about the way `scope` configuration is set. In order to setup two-way data binding with isolated scope you should provide corresponding attribute in HTML:

```
<news-article ng-repeat="item in news" item="item"></news-article>
```

and then setup directive accordingly:

```
scope: {
    item: '='
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/b1I8PIc27MvjVeQaCDON?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was missing. The whole scope thing is very confusing to newbies.